# HTML Graphs with php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help i m using html5 cnavasjs for graphs the graph is repeate
the php code is

```
window.onload = function () {
                            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                                theme: "theme2",//theme1
                                animationEnabled: true,
                                 zoomEnabled:true,
                                title:{
                                    text: "Basic Column Chart Of Student in Current Year"   ,
                                    fontColor: "#0A89C4"
                               },

                                data: [              
                                {

                  // Change type to "bar", "splineArea", "area", "spline", "pie",etc.
                                    type: "column",

                                    dataPoints: [
                                         <?php foreach ($std as $row3){?>
                                    { label: "<?php echo $row3['obj_full_month'];?>", y: <?php echo count($row3['obj_student_id']);?> },

                                    <?php
                                        }
                                     ?>
                                    ]

                                }

                                ]

                            });

                            chart.render();
                        }
```

And the mysql query is

```
SELECT * FROM `obj_organisation`,`obj_student`,`obj_student_graph`
                        WHERE obj_organisation.obj_org_id = obj_student.obj_org_id
                        AND
                        obj_organisation.obj_org_id = obj_student_graph.obj_org_id
                        AND
                        obj_student.obj_student_id = obj_student_graph.obj_student_id
                        AND
                        obj_student_graph.obj_org_id = '$id'
                        AND
                        obj_student_graph.obj_year = '$year'!
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `Distinct` : `SELECT DISTINCT obj_full_month, obj_student_id FROM ...`?

Comment: you have 3 results. is it expected or like Mahmoud said repitition caused by your sql query?

Comment: What is the problem with your data? and what are you trying to do? do you want to eliminate repeated data? or you want to sum them? you might need to sum the number of students for each month?